# Facebook API and Safari

Tags: asp.net, facebook, cookies, safari

**Update and solution:** It turns out the problem was based on a redirect I used for my dev URL, which resulted in browsers perceiving all cookies set by my page as third-party cookies. The Facebook JS API session cookie is *not* set as a third-party cookie.

I'm working on an ASP.NET application with Facebook authentication. For this I use [Microsofts Facebook SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574) in combination with Facebooks Javascript API. Everything's working, except for Safari. Safaris default setting is to not accept third-party cookies, which results in:

- I can access the Facebook session through Javascript.
- I can NOT access the Facebook session server-side, because the cookie is never set and sent from Safari.

This is my client-side code related to Facebook (JS):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>    
<fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({ appId: 'myAppId', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
       if (response.session) {
           window.location.reload(); //Results in eternal reload of page
       }
    });
</script>
```

This is my code for fetching the user id server-side (C#):

```
public string FacebookUserID
{
    get
    {
        FacebookSettings settings = new FacebookSettings();
        settings.AppId = "myAppId";
        settings.AppSecret = "myAppSecret";
        FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(settings);
        Authorizer auth = new Authorizer(app);

        return (auth.IsAuthorized()) ? app.Session.UserId : null;
    }
}
```

I guess I'm not the only one with the same problem, but I've searched both the Facebook Developer forum and here and haven't found a solution. It's really more of a Safari problem than a Facebook-specific problem.

I've been thinking about posting the user-id back to the server through GET/POST/my own cookie, but that is an ugly solution and a potential security issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a Safari problem because anyone can set their browser of choice to not allow third party cookies and it would break the functionality (at least from what you're saying). Have you tried changing the 3rd party cookies settings in other browsers to see if things still work or not work?

Comment: That is correct, the problem was related to third-party-cookies primarily, and Safari secondly because of its default setting of disallowing third-party cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the problem was based on a redirect I used for my dev URL, which resulted in browsers perceiving all cookies set by my page as third-party cookies. The Facebook JS API session cookie is not set as a third-party cookie.

Comment: I have the same issue. I don't understand how it can work for you. Are you sure it does?
When the FB JS sets a cookie for my application, it's for my application's domain (myapp.com) and not for facebook.com. It's a third-party cookie, isn't it?

Comment: I have the issue where session state is not maintained, I am not sure what the solution actually is here?