# Safari session always forgets session variables in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, safari

I am building a small web application and in my application I am using the session object to store information across calls to server. This works quite fine in Firefox \ Chrome\ IE, but it seems to fail in Safari. In Safari the session keeps forgetting that I've stored values in it.

Why is this happening? what can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The session is based on an id stored in a cookie. The server uses this Id to link to your session on the server. It's highly likely cookies are off here. Load up fiddler or turn on tracing to see what cookies are being sent over... You should see the one with aspnetsessionid in it, if not your browser prob has them turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look over here: [Facebook API and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846283/facebook-api-and-safari)

Looks like, if any redirect is sent when you are establishing cookies, they will be viewed as 3rd party cookies and could cause issues with your server-side.

Answer (score 0):

if your settings on Safari are set to not allow cookies, then this fails. I have just had the same issue on an iphone web app im writing. I enabled cookies and all worked fine.

Answer (score -3):

The whole idea of the Session is that the values are stored server-side. Safari can't possibly cause the server to forget something. Either the value wasn't ever stored in the Session or Safari is failing to render the Session value.

Trying using a debugger to confirm if the Session holds the correct value when passing the value into the Session and when you're attempting to retrieve the value from the Session.

Comment: This answer is wrong, the issue is obviously related to Safari not allowing cookies. Rather than downvoting though, I would rather give you the chance to make an edit to correct you answer, or delete the post, or whatever you think is best